# Strange inequality in an NT problem

Tags: number-theory, inequality, contest-math, divisibility

If $a\neq b$ are positive integers and $a^2+ab+b^2 | ab(a+b)$ then show that $|a-b|>\sqrt[3]{ab}$.

WLOG $a>b$. $a^2+ab+b^2 | ab(a+b)-a(a^2+ab+b^2)=-a^3$, so we have $a^2+ab+b^2$ divides $a^3$ as well as $b^3$. From here I tried lots of things, but I don't think they are worth of mentioning. If you have any idea ,do not hesitate to suggest.

Comment: Equivalently we may show $(a-b)^3 \gt ab$.

Comment: Since this is contest-math, please indicate a source, so that we know it’s not an ongoing problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $$a^2+ab+b^2\mid ab(a+b)\iff a^2+ab+b^2\mid a^3\iff a^2+ab+b^2\mid b^3$$ $$\iff a^2+ab+b^2\mid \gcd(a,b)^3$$

Thus, let $d:=\gcd(a,b)$, and let $x:=\frac{a}d, y:=\frac{b}d$. It follows that $$a^2+ab+b^2\mid \gcd(a,b)^3\iff x^2+xy+y^2\mid d\implies d>xy$$

You are left to show that $\lvert a-b\rvert>\sqrt[3]{ab}\iff \lvert dx-dy\rvert^3=\lvert a-b\rvert^3> ab = d^2\cdot xy\iff d\lvert x-y\rvert > xy$. But this is trivial, since $d>xy$ and $\lvert x-y\rvert\geqslant 1.$

Comment: @CalvinLin You are, of course, right.

Comment: In fact, since $ d > 3xy$, we have $ |a-b | > 3 \sqrt[3]{ab} $.  $\quad$ Makes me wonder what the contest setters were thinking about.

Comment: @CalvinLin You are absolutely right. I wonder if there is an alternative method that only shows the weaker estimate... I seems to me, however, that this should be the standard approach, but then, why $\sqrt[3]{ab}$ and not $3\sqrt[3]{ab}$?

Comment: This process is very standard. In fact, OP's observation of the algebraic manipulation leading to $a^3, b^3$ was nice, but not necessary. We have $ x^2 + xy + y^2 \mid d xy(x+y)$, and verify term wise that $ \gcd(x^2+xy+y^2, xy(x+y) ) = 1$ which leads to the conclusion of $x^2 + xy +y^2 \mid d \Rightarrow d > 3xy$.